# Delta/Scott-wye/Scott?

Tags: transformer, identification

I’m a level two electrician so we haven’t been taught about 3 phase even though I work with it all the time and I think I have an ok understanding.
I can’t find any information on this transformer and I don’t understand why it looks the way it does.

[image]

Can anyone point me in a direction to research?  Thank you in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott-T_transformer  Note that 3 phase diagrams are drawn such that the physical angle is the same as the electrical phase angle.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where have you encountered this?  Note the X0 terminal allows you to get the voltage relationships of a wye connection.  At one time I saw these used as a way to avoid the circulating primary currents that can occur in a delta-wye transformer with a lot of harmonic distortion in the secondary current.  They tend to have poor voltage balance with varying loads.

Comment: I was curious about that. I didn’t know if that was an artistic decision or if I was supposed to look that deep into that thank you @Mattman944

Comment: I am a maintenance electrician for a big company and one of the companies we own is a demolition company and we must’ve got it off of a demo job. What does the zigzag lines mean? I understand the dotted but not the zigzag @theodore

Comment: @KeeganMartin The zig-zag is just another way of drawing the usual spiral indicating the transformer winding.

Comment: So is it a delta to delta/wye transformer? Oh is there some other name when referring to these transformers? @Theodore

Comment: It's just called T/T.  It's not a Scott-T because neither winding is intended for two phase.  When I have a chance, I will edit my comments into a proper answer.

Comment: @KeeganMartin Do you have a photo of the complete nameplate?  I noticed something that may change my answer.

Comment: @theodore I do and I would have posted the complete version but this website doesn’t let me what would you like to know? It’s 600 -120/208. It’s a 30kva. H1&2 had 3 voltage taps, H3 had like 5. Type: TWM. %imp: 3,4. Spec: 4512. Temp 150°C. Poids wt: 300 (?)